# Cannot assign to mapMeasures[ts].Delta

Tags: go

I have a type:

```
type Measure struct {
    Timestamp     time.Time
    Delta         float64
}
```

I am converting a slice of measures to a map with the timestamp as key:

```
func MeasuresToMap(measures []models.Measure) map[string]models.Measure {
    mapMeasures := make(map[string]models.Measure, len(measures)) //
    for _, measure := range measures {
        mapMeasures[measure.Timestamp.Format(time.RFC3339)] = measure
    }
    return mapMeasures
}
```

And I do:

```
mapMeasures := misc.MeasuresToMap(myMeasures)
for ts, _ := range mapMeasures {
        mapMeasures[ts].Delta = 0
    }
```

And I get:

```
Cannot assign to mapMeasures[ts].Delta
```

but what I can do:

```
for ts, measure := range mapMeasures {
        measure.Delta = 0
        mapMeasures[ts] = measure
    }
```

What is the difference between the 2 options, why can't I update directly Delta field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign to something you **cannot get the address** of.

That's the case with `mapMeasures[ts].Delta = 0` - you cannot take the address of `Measure`. Here's what *The Go Programming Language (A. Donovan, B. Kernighan)* book has to say about taking an address of a map element:

> One reason that we can’t take the address of a map element is that growing a map might cause rehashing of existing elements into new storage locations, thus potentially invalidating the address.

On the other hand, when you do `for ts, measure := range mapMeasures {...}` you create an explicit variable `measure` and therefore you're able to take its address and assign to it.